# Aggregate Data Without Group By

Tags: count, datediff

I'm trying to create a single row of data, but the Group By clause is screwing me up.

Here's my table:

```
RegistrationPK  :  DateBirth   : RegistrationDate
```

I'm trying to get the age of people at the time of Registration.

What I have is:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateBirth,RegistrationDate) < 20 THEN COUNT(registrationpk) END AS Under20
FROM dbo.Registration r
GROUP BY r.DOB, r.RegDate
```

Instead of getting one column "Under20" with one row of data, I get all the different DateBirth rows.

How can I do a `DateDiff` without a `Group By`?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, but I hate Selects within Selects.  If anyone knows a simpler way I'd appreciate it.  For some reason, when done as a select within a select, SQL doesn't require either statement to have the GroupBy clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(UNDER20) AS UNDER20
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            UNDER20 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateBirth,regdate) < 20 THEN '1'    END
            FROM dbo.Registration r
            ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
 SELECT 
     SUM (
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateBirth,regdate) < 20 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
     ) 
 FROM dbo.Registration r
```